# Java - monitor values of objects/variables held on server, from client-side

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I have a server application that has instances of a class called `BidItem`. Clients can connect to the server (each through their own separate thread in a `ClientHandler` class), and place bids on the items held on the server. This will update the `BidItem`'s `highbid` attribute.

What I would like is for all clients to be able to monitor the `highBid` attribute of the `BidItem`s, so that a message can be output on the client GUI when a new `highBid` value is detected.

I have asked a couple of previous questions relating to this here on StackOverflow while I was still getting my head around how this would be implemented, here is what I have put together so far:

- The client application will need to run a separate thread to monitor the value of this variable in the background
- This thread will need to make use of `synchronized` blocks, as well as Java's `wait()` and `notifyAll()` methods for communication with other threads

This all works fine in my head, there is just one thing I'm struggling with to get the whole idea to work. As mentioned before, the `BidItem`s are held on the server and passed into the `ClientHandler` for each client that connects, and this is where Items can be updated.
What I'm struggling with is how my new Thread on the client-side would be able to access the `highBid` attribute of the `BidItem` to be able to monitor changes, as the `BidItem` instances are never passed into the Client.

Here is a sketch code of what I'm after, I just need to work out how to get the values into the variables:

CLIENT CLASS:

```
//set up socket and input/output streams
socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
//input stream from the socket connected to
networkInput = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
//output stream to the socket connected to
output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

//set up thread to monitor values held on server
BidMonitor bidMonitor = new BidMonitor();
bidMonitor.start();
```

BidMonitor CLASS:

```
public class BidMonitor extends Thread
{
    public synchronized void run()
    {
        while (valueHeldOnClient == valueHeldOnServer)
        {
            wait();
        }
        valueHeldOnClient = valueHeldOnServer;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this gives some idea of what I'm after, but feel free to ask questions!
Any help on this would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: I find your question a bit broad/unclear. Are you asking how you connect & send & receive data for client and server? Are you asking for the best way to communicate this information?

Comment: The client and the server don't share any memory. If you want to access information that exists on the server from the client, either the client should ask it to the server on a regular basis, or the server should send it to the client when it changes. But you need network communication.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this. I have input and output streams between my server and client which allow messages to be sent backwards and forwards, but I have been instructed that the monitoring of this value should be done 'via a waiting thread' on the client side, and have very little idea how to accomplish this. How could data be sent from the server to the monitoring thread on a regular basis? @JBNizet

Comment: Input and output between my client and server works fine, it is getting this data into the separate monitoring thread on the client side that I am struggling with. @Jägermeister

Comment: "via a waiting thread" can also mean that this thread simply calls `networkInput.nextInt()` (or so) which blocks until the server sends something. That's a waiting thread. I can't see how you could use `wait()` because that will only work if something within your client calls `notify`. PS: your `run` method is currently only a deadlock because the notify happens after the wait, which can't happen because it's waiting on it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. With this approach, would I have to set up a new input stream in this Thread to take input straight from the server (therefore not interrupting the other interaction in the main Client program)? @zapl

Comment: You should probably have only 1 inputstream / connection from your server to each client. The monitor thread can use the same one as the rest of the program if you make sure that you don't read from the stream from two places at the same time. Requires some synchronization (e.g. wrapping all reads in `synchronized(networkInput)` everywhere should work)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have a look into it! @zapl

Answer (score 0):

If this is more than just a programming exercise, I would suggest not implementing network protocols for a common use case like this. I would suggest using a queuing system to publish changes to `BidItem`. Every time an item changes, you push a message to the queue. Clients that are interested in receiving updates subscribe to the queue. Look at technologies like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/). These are already written for you, and they've solved problems that you haven't even considered yet. There are Java client libraries that make implementing this a breeze. See this [tutorial](http://www.coderpanda.com/jms-example-using-apache-activemq/).

As a side note, using sockets directly is typically not good design. Sockets require you to design and implement a client and server protocol, and there are usually things you haven't thought about. E.g. why not use HTTP and web services?